# Why the size_ip is coming out to be 0?

Tags: libpcap

```
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*) (packet);
const u_int16_t type = ethernet->ether_type;
switch (ntohs(type))
{
    case ETHERTYPE_IP:
        printf("Sniffed IPv4 packet\n");
        break;
    case ETHERTYPE_IPV6:
        printf("Sniffed IPv6 packet\n");
        break;
}

ip = (struct sniff_ip*) (packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
size_ip = IP_HL(ip) * 4;
if (size_ip < 20)
{
    printf("Packet Capture, Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
    return;
}
```

The size_ip for IPv4 always is correct. However for IPv6 case I am getting the size_ip as 0 always. I have tried to dump IPv6 packets that are sniffed into a file and they look to be fine. Anyone has idea as why the size_ip is coming out to be 0?

Comment: IPv6 is entirely different from IPv4. While we cannot see how you defined your `struct sniff_ip`, it is entirely unreasonable that you can use the same struct for an IPv6 header as you do for IPv4. Refer to e.g. to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet , IPv6 does not even have a header length field.

Comment: Hey. Yes I was wrong to use IPv4 generic header for both the cases. However I have one more question.  I am using   size_ip  as done above to advance to TCP packet as ip_hl field gives the header length. How will this happen in IPv6. I am not finding an example online that gives me an idea as how to exactly declare IPv6 header